# append an element only once on click event

Tags: jquery, chat

how do i check if an element exists before executing the event handler , because in my case each time as long as i click on a link a new chatbox is appended, on the other hand how to detect that there is no more space horizontally for a chatbox

```js
$('.PBChatFriendsList > li a').on('click',function(){
    var $username = $(this).data('username'),
     $chatBoxHeader = $('<div>',{'class': 'chatBoxHeader'}).append("<h4>" + $username + "</h4>"),
     $messsageContent = $('<div>',{'class': 'messsageContent'}),
     $messageContainer = $('<div>',{'class':'messageContainer'}).append($messsageContent),
     $chatBoxForm = $('<form>',{method : 'post', id : 'chatBoxReplayForm'}),
     $chatBoxInput = $('<div>',{'class':'chatBoxInput'}).append($chatBoxForm),
     $chatBoxbody = $('<div>',{'class':'chatBoxbody'}).append($messageContainer);
     $chatBox = $('<div>',{'class' : 'chatBox opened _PBTab'}).append($chatBoxHeader,$chatBoxbody,$chatBoxInput);
    $('.chatBoxGroup').prepend($chatBox);
     
    
   });
```

```css
.PBChatFriendsList >li > a{padding: 2px 14px 2px 8px; display: block; height: 38px; box-sizing: border-box;}
.PBChatFriendsList >li:hover{background-color: #f5f1f1;}
.friendChatPhoto{float: left; width: 34px; height: 34px; display: inline-block;}
.chatFriendFullName{padding: 0 0 0 8px; float: left; display: inline-block; text-overflow:ellipsis; overflow: hidden;}
.chatFriendFullName > span{font-size: 0.78em; line-height: 34px; color: #555454;}
.chatFriendStatus{float: right; display: inline-block;}
.userConDispositif{font-weight: 500; color: green; font-size: 0.7em; line-height: 30px; display: inline-block;}

/*--------------chatbox--------------------*/
.PBchatBoxContainer{position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 256px; height: 300px; background-color: white;}
.PBChatBoxContainerRight{left: auto; right: 300px; bottom: 0; position: fixed; z-index: 40;}
.PBBlock{margin: 0 14px 0 0;}
.chatbContainer{float: right;}
.chatBox.opened{margin-left: 10px; width: 240px; background-color: green;}
._PBTab{height: 28px;}
.chatBoxs, .chatBoxGroup, .chatBoxGroup > div{float: left; position: relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="PBChatFriendsContainer clearfix">
                                    <ul class="PBChatFriendsList">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" data-username="John Diggle">
                                                <div class="chatFriendContainer">
                                                    <div class="friendChatPhoto">
                                                        <img src="img/chat_user_photo.jpg" alt="tarek hatem">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="chatFriendFullName">
                                                        <span>John Diggle</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="chatFriendStatus">
                                                        <div class="userConDispositif">web</div>
                                                        <i class="online-icon"></i>
                                                    </div>                                           
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!--endof list element-->
                                         <li>
                                            <a href="#" data-username="Tarek Hatem">
                                                <div class="chatFriendContainer">
                                                    <div class="friendChatPhoto">
                                                        <img src="img/chat_user_photo.jpg" alt="tarek hatem">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="chatFriendFullName">
                                                        <span>Tarek Hatem</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="chatFriendStatus">
                                                        <div class="userConDispositif">web</div>
                                                        <i class="online-icon"></i>
                                                    </div>                                           
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!--endof list element-->
                                         <li>
                                            <a href="#" data-username="Malcom Merlyn">
                                                <div class="chatFriendContainer">
                                                    <div class="friendChatPhoto">
                                                        <img src="img/chat_user_photo.jpg" alt="tarek hatem">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="chatFriendFullName">
                                                        <span>Malcom Merlyn</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="chatFriendStatus">
                                                        <div class="userConDispositif">web</div>
                                                        <i class="online-icon"></i>
                                                    </div>                                           
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li><!--endof list element-->
                                        
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
<div class="chatbox_outer_container">
  <div class="PBChatBoxContainer PBChatBoxContainerRight">
    <div class="PBBlock clearfix">
      <div class="chatbContainer clearfix">
        <div class="chatBoxs">
          <div class="chatBoxGroup clearfix">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need **$.one()**: _http://api.jquery.com/one/_

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the chatbox already exists in the DOM before appending:

```
$('.PBChatFriendsList > li a').on('click',function(){
    if($('.chatBoxHeader').length == 0){
         //Code to append chatbox to the dom
    }
});
```

In case there are more than one `.chatBoxHeader`, you can assign each an `id` attribute that's unique and then

```
$('.PBChatFriendsList > li a').on('click',function(){
    if($('#unique-id-for-each-chatheader').length == 0){
         //Code to append chatbox to the dom
    }
});
```

Comment: but what if there is another chatbox related to another element , so when you click on any other element nothing will happen

Comment: Edited original answer